# Is there a way to optionally not have filepicker.io store your uploads in their servers/database?

Tags: filepicker.io

maybe I just haven't read the documentation thoroughly enough, but it seems like if you want to use the S3 option, it's typically because you want to serve your uploads from that S3 location.  So once your stuff is in S3, it doesn't need to be saved at a filepicker url anymore.  Is there any way to specify that you want an upload stored in S3, and *not* with filepicker, making filepicker simply a middle man?

One would expect that if this were possible, it would entail some type of reduced cost due to the fact that filepicker isn't storing all that data for us.  If this is possible, would uploads stored in S3 and not filepicker still count towards our file limit for the account type we have?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify an S3 location, Filepicker.io does not store the contents of the file on our servers, which is why the pricing plans are done on # of files rather than size, etc. On both the `filepicker.store()` and the `filepicker.pickAndStore()` calls, the FPFile that is returned will have a `key` parameter that indicates where in your S3 bucket the file is stored.

From this, you can construct the S3 url as necessary, but by default we provide the filepicker.io url which serves as both the unique identifier to the file, as well as providing options like `/convert`, `/stat`, etc.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Why's there a filepicker.io url if it's not stored at filepicker?  Are you saying that using the filepicker.io url will actually fetch the file from my S3 bucket and feed it back?